# Unique() gives me the same value more than once in R vector

Tags: r

I have the vector below

```
c("SSD", "PCIe SSD", "PCIe SSD", "PCIe SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "TB SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "PCIe SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "PCle SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "HDD", "HDD", "HDD", "N/A", "HDD", "‎HDD", 
"N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "Hybrid Drive", "HDD", "‎SSD", "‎HDD", 
"SSD", "N/A", "SSD", "N/A", "SSD", "SSD", "‎SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "‎SSD", "‎SSD", "‎SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "PCIe SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "eMMC", "SSD", "Flash Memory", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "eMMC", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "Flash Memory", "SSD", "SSD", NA, "SSD", "SSD", "M.2 PCI", 
"M.2 PCI", "SSD", "M.2 PCI", "M.2 PCI", "N/A", "SSD", "HDD", 
"M.2 PCI", "HDD", "M.2 PCI", "Flash/SSD", "M.2 PCI", "NVMe M.2", 
"N/A", "M.2 PCI", "HDD", "SSD", "M.2 PCI", "NVMe M.2", "M.2 PCI", 
"M.2 PCI", "M.2 PCI", "M.2 PCI", "M.2 PCI", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"M.2 PCI", "SSD", "M.2 PCI", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"M.2 PCI", "SSD", "M.2 PCI", "HDD", "SSD", "M.2 PCI", "SSD", 
"HDD", "NVMe M.2", "Hybrid Drive", "N/A", "N/A", "HDD", "N/A", 
"SSD", "SSD", "M.2 PCI", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "HDD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "NVMe M.2 PCI", "SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "Flash", "SSD", 
"SSD", "NVMe M.2 PCI", "SSD", "SSD", "‎HDD", "SSD", "SSD", 
"SSD", "SSD", "SSD", "HDD", "‎SSD", "HDD", "‎SSD", "‎SSD", 
"DVDRW", "N/A", "HDD", "HDD", "‎SSD", "HDD", "HDD", "‎SSD", 
"N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "SSD", NA, NA)
```

and when I try to find its unique values I get some values like "HDD" twice. why dont I get it only once?

```
unique(data0$`Storage Type`)
 [1] "SSD"          "PCIe SSD"     "TB SSD"       "PCle SSD"     "HDD"          "N/A"          "‎HDD"         
 [8] "Hybrid Drive" "‎SSD"          "eMMC"         "Flash Memory" NA             "M.2 PCI"      "Flash/SSD"   
[15] "NVMe M.2"     "NVMe M.2 PCI" "Flash"        "DVDRW"    



sessionInfo()

R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: Europe/Bucharest
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] zoo_1.8-12        compiler_4.3.1    tools_4.3.1       rstudioapi_0.15.0 grid_4.3.1        lattice_0.21-8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As identified in the comments and previous answer, some of your `"HDD"` and `"SSD"` values contain hidden characters.

You can identify those entries using the `tools::showNonASCII()` function, e.g. if I set `st` to your vector,

```
tools::showNonASCII(unique(st))
# 7: <e2><80><8e>HDD
# 9: <e2><80><8e>SSD
# 12: NA
```

To remove any non-ASCII strings, use `iconv(to = "ASCII", sub = "")`:

```
ascii <- iconv(st, to = "ASCII", sub = "")
tools::showNonASCII(unique(ascii))
# 10: NA
```

Answer (score 8):

Some of the `HDD` strings have hidden characters:

```
> cat(rawToChar(charToRaw(unique(dat)[7])), "\n")
‎ HDD 
> cat(rawToChar(charToRaw(unique(dat)[5])), "\n")
HDD
```

You can actually see this if you paste it into a terminal

`"<200e>‎HDD"`

So your data contains `<200e>‎` which is a left-to-right mark which is a non-printable unicode representation.

### iconv approach

Strip any non-ASCII characters like this:

```
dat = iconv(dat, to = "ASCII//TRANSLIT")
```

or (thanks to jpsmith)

```
dat =  iconv(dat, from = "ASCII", to = "latin1")
```

```
> unique(dat)
 [1] "SSD"          "PCIe SSD"     "TB SSD"       "PCle SSD"     "HDD"         
 [6] "N/A"          NA             "Hybrid Drive" "eMMC"         "Flash Memory"
[11] "M.2 PCI"      "Flash/SSD"    "NVMe M.2"     "NVMe M.2 PCI" "Flash"       
[16] "DVDRW"
```

### regex approach

If this doesn't, then we can use good old regex to match anything which isn't in the regular ASCII character:

```
library(stringr)

dat[str_detect(dat, "[^\x01-\x7F]")]

 [1] "‎HDD" "‎SSD" "‎HDD" "‎SSD" "‎SSD" "‎SSD" "‎SSD" NA    "‎HDD" "‎SSD" "‎SSD" "‎SSD"
[13] "‎SSD" "‎SSD" NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

then

```
data = ifelse(data %in% NA, NA, str_remove_all(data, "[^\x01-\x7F]"))
unique(data)

 [1] "SSD"          "PCIe SSD"     "TB SSD"       "PCle SSD"     "HDD"         
 [6] "N/A"          "Hybrid Drive" "eMMC"         "Flash Memory" NA            
[11] "M.2 PCI"      "Flash/SSD"    "NVMe M.2"     "NVMe M.2 PCI" "Flash"       
[16] "DVDRW"
```

Comment: how can I fix this in order to keep pnly the main characters?

Comment: I get a "?" next to "HDD" unique(data0$`Storage Type`)
 [1] "SSD"          "PCIe SSD"     "TB SSD"       "PCle SSD"     "HDD"          "N/A"          "?HDD"        
 [8] "Hybrid Drive" "?SSD"         "eMMC"         "Flash Memory" NA             "M.2 PCI"      "Flash/SSD"   
[15] "NVMe M.2"     "NVMe M.2 PCI" "Flash"        "DVDRW"       
>

Comment: Not sure - can't reproduce tht

Comment: same error. how can I help you reproduce it?

Comment: add ``sessionInfo()`` - it may be platform or locale specific

Comment: OK I added it now

Comment: ibrary(stringr)
> data0$`Storage Type`[str_detect(data0$`Storage Type`, "[^\x01-\x7F]")]
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
> 
> data0$`Storage Type` = ifelse(data0$`Storage Type` %in% NA, NA, str_remove_all(data0$`Storage Type`, "[^\x01-\x7F]"))
> unique(data0$`Storage Type`)
 [1] "SSD"          "PCIe SSD"     "TB SSD"       "PCle SSD"     "HDD"          "N/A"          "?HDD"        
 [8] "Hybrid Drive" "?SSD"         "eMMC"         "Flash Memory" NA             "M.2 PCI"      "Flash/SSD"   
[15] "NVMe M.2"     "NVMe M.2 PCI" "Flash"        "DVDRW"       same issue with regex

Comment: dat<-data0$`Storage Type`[str_detect(data0$`Storage Type`, "[^\x01-\x7F]")]
data = ifelse(dat %in% NA, NA, str_remove_all(dat, "[^\x01-\x7F]"))
unique(data)
[1] "HDD" "SSD" NA  basically that skipped all th other values too

Comment: thanks but the issue is to clear this vector